# how to get the current location in latitude and longitude in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location, latitude-longitude

I am using the following code to get the current location,I have added the corelocation framework

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
    int minutes = decimal * 60;
    double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@" Current Latitude : %@",lat);
    //latLabel.text = lat;
    degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
    minutes = decimal * 60;
    seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                       degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@" Current Longitude : %@",longt);
    //longLabel.text = longt;
}
```

But i am getting the default values i.e, Latitude : 42° 17' 36.8898" and Longitude : -71° 27' 43.1003"
where my current Latitude:N 12° 56' 11.5624" and Longitude:E 77° 32' 41.0834". How to get the exact latitude and longitude.
where i am doing the mistake or do i need to add any other method or function or framework.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you test on real device or simulator?

Comment: Have you enabled location services on your device?

Comment: @XSlash I tested on simulator.

Comment: @H2CO3 I am not checking on the device

Comment: Did you enable location simulator on your XCode?

Comment: I doubt you'll get real location data on the simulator. Go ahead and install on the device.

Comment: @XSlash how to enable the location simulator on Xcode.

Comment: see my answer , but it has its limitation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the application on real device. The Simulator will always show you the default value for Latitude and Longitude. Also make sure that the location services are enabled on your device.

Comment: Even on the simulator it shouldn't be a problem. Inside the debug area you can see next to the debug buttons, you can select different areas. There are some default positions you can choose fore testing. Or you create your own on!

Answer (score 14):

You can add this method where you need to get the current latitude and longitude:

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

    return coordinate;
}
```

And to call it use:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

NSLog(@"*dLatitude : %@", latitude);
NSLog(@"*dLongitude : %@",longitude);
```

Comment: I have the odd behaviour that `coordinate`s are (null) when i try t access them directly. And the impression, if the code has some time the coordinates are delivered. Seems like a timing issue.

Comment: This returns 0.000000 for Latitude and Longitude.  I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 and iPhone 5s simulator. Why so?

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this answer. Really Really Help for beginners.

Comment: This returns 0.000000 for Latitude and Longitude every time

Answer (score 2):

You have to test location service in device, not simulator, though you can enable location simulation on simulator, see my image attachment, the circled icon. But it won't be your exact location! But at least you can verify your code is working
[image]

Comment: run your app, then it'll appear

Comment: @X Slash, after running my app only i checked it, but it is not showing any icon as u showed.

Comment: @shasha Go to `product`->`Edit Scheme`->`Options`->select `Allow Location simulation` then you'll get the icon X slash is mentioning, even if you enable that you won't get _your_ latitude and longitude

Answer (score 1):

You need to test it on a device to get your current location's latitude and longitude, i'm guessing you are getting Cupertino's latitude and longitude which is a default.

Answer (score 0):

First You should enable Location Service in your Simulator. Debug -> Location. Most of the case you will be getting lat and long values of Cupertino. And you can set Custom locations for this option by selecting the second option(Custom Location). These option will automatically triggered when we are selecting location when runtime in Debugging area.