# angularjs:ionic IOS emulator is showing wrong GPS co-ordinates

Tags: ios, angularjs

In ionic angularjs
I'm trying to get the Latitude and Longitude of my current location.

It is giving my current location correctly when I'm running it on the browser , but when I run it on IOS emulator it is giving some sanfransisco address.

COntroller.js

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {

LocationService.GetLocation().then(function(data){
console.log(data.latitude,data.longitude);
  var code="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+data.latitude+","+data.longitude;

  $http.get(code).success(function(dataval){
        //console.log(dataval.results[0]);
        $("#Locationval").text(dataval.results[0]["formatted_address"])
      });
});
});
```

Service.js

```
appnService.factory('LocationService', function($q){

var currentLocation = {
    latitude:"",
    longitude:""
}

return {
    GetLocation : function(){
            var d = $q.defer();
            //console.log(d);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
        currentLocation.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
        currentLocation.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
        d.resolve(currentLocation);
    });
    return d.promise
}
};
});
```

On browser I'm Getting latitude=11.9384867 Longitude=79.8352657(These are correct)
On IOS emulator I'm getting latitude=37.785834 Longitude= -122.406417 (These are wrong)

Please help me with this

Thankyou

Comment: you need to change the simulator location to current location. other wise show you the static define locations only.

Comment: why to change the location in simulator. Why cant it get the GPS location?

Comment: Because its a simulator. it just provide some predefine location for testing in it. run the same code on device you will find you current location in it

Comment: Thankyou for your response Gaurav.. I just found some info at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998558/how-to-get-the-current-location-in-latitude-and-longitude-in-objective-c), this might be helpful..

Comment: I have said the same thing

Comment: simualator always show default location only.

Comment: Yeah Gaurav..Just gave the link..Thankyou very much..